# custom Validator for value

Tags: angular, validation

i need help to make a forbidden validator for the number 0.

I have searching for hours without results.

I know I need a function but how to make it ?

client and Group needs to forbidden the value 0

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyLampCreateDialogComponent>, private fixtureService: FixtureService, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      client: [null, Validators.min(-1)],
      group: [null, Validators.min(-1)],
      name: [null, Validators.maxLength(255)],
      led_spec: [null]
    });
  }
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Doesn't having a minimum value of 1 make it so that 0 is invalid?

Comment: i've make mistake, it's -1  and value 0 is forbidden

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on the web for custom validators for Angular. https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/ is one. Doing a search for "angular custom validators" finds quite a lot...

Comment: You might also want to look at the [angular-custom-validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-custom-validators) tag here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes I checked it but how tell to !control.value === 0 , it doesn't work like this

Comment: Because the syntax is `control.value !== 0`...